# When is $\overline{1x1yxy}$ divisible by $63$?

Tags: arithmetic

Given 
 $$N=\overline {1x1yxy}\ ^{\left( 10\right) }$$

Determine $x$ and $y$ such that :$$63 \mid  N$$

Comment: Is this a tenth power or does this symbolize that we are talking about a number $N$ with base-10 digits as specified?

Comment: Numbers in the decimal base .

Comment: I think he's asking us for help to find a base ten number with digits $1x1yxy$ that is divisible by $63$.

Comment: Yes that's it ,

Comment: You Why should this question be downvoted ,have I done something wrong?

Comment: Well the question wasn't clear, I had no idea that you were asking whether the number is divisible by $63$ (without reading the comments) also no $N$ was introduced earlier and for last you didn't really put any effort on your side except for the statement of the problem (which wasn't complete).

Comment: I understand,sorry my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $1x1yxy$ is divisible by 9, $1+x+1+y+x+y=2(1+x+y)$ must be divisible by 9, so $1+x+y$ must be divisible by 9.  Since $x$ and $y$ are digits between 0 and 9, $1+x+y$ is between 1 and 19 so it must be either 9 or 18.  Hence $x+y$ is either 8 or 17.

Now note that $$0 \equiv 1x1yxy = 100000+10000x+1000+100y+10x+y \equiv 5+4x+6+2y+3x+y \\ = 11+7x+3y \equiv 4+3y \pmod{7}.$$
Hence $3y \equiv 3 \pmod7$ so $y \equiv 1\pmod7$.  Thus $y = 1$ or $y = 8$ since it is a digit.

This yields the four solutions $(x,y) = (7,1), (0,8), (16,1), (9,8)$, but clearly $(16,1)$ doesn't work since 16 isn't a digit.  Thus there are three possible answers: $171171, 101808, 191898.$

Answer (score 2):

The digit sum is $2(1+x+y)$ and must be a multiple of $9$ to make $N$ a multiple of $9$. That is, $x+y=8$ or $x+y=17$ (which means they are $8$ and $9$ in some order).

As $1001$ is a multiple of $7$, we need that $\overline{yxy}-\overline{1x1}=(y-1)\cdot 101$ is a multiple of $7$. So $y=1$ or $y=8$. In the first case, we may have $x=7$, in the second caase $x=0$ or $x=9$.

Answer (score 1):

**Divisibility by $9$ Rule:** The sum of the digits must be divisible by $9$.

**Divisibility by $7$ Rule:** To find out if a number is divisible by seven, take the last digit, double it, and subtract it from the rest of the number. If you get an answer divisible by 7 (including zero), then the original number is divisible by seven. If you don't know the new number's divisibility, you can apply the rule again.

[Source for Divisibility Rules](http://staff.argyll.epsb.ca/jreed/math7/strand1/1104.htm).
The [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule) article also has a whole bunch of information, including how a lot of these divisibility rules are derived.